# Desktop Window manager crashes with aero on rotated dual-screens

Tags: windows-vista, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, crash, window-manager

I just got a new monitor and plugged it into my computer and got two displays working just fine.  I have the original monitor (1680x1050) and the new one (768x1024).  The second monitor is rotated 90 degrees clockwise so the two (almost) have the same height.  My problem arose when I tried to rotate the second one's display using the NVIDIA Control Panel.  The DWM crashed right as I dragged a window into the new screen.

- The DWM only crashes if the display is set to Aero
- The DWM does not crash if the screens are rotated the same way
- The DWM crashes when a dragged window enters the rotated screen or after a few seconds
- Windows Vista Home Premium
- NVIDIA GeForce 9400 GT version 311.06

Why does the DWM crash under these conditions?  I want Aero enabled (which requires the DWM), but I also want to keep this monitor setup; is this possible?

Comment: have you tried the 326.41 beta driver? http://www.nvidia.com/object/win8-win7-winvista-32bit-326.41-beta-driver.html http://www.nvidia.com/object/win8-win7-winvista-64bit-326.41-beta-driver.html

Comment: I just installed that and my display won't even work AT ALL on either screen -_-*  That card made my problem at least 100 times worse.  Now can you tell me how to uninstall/roll back that driver?  I booted my computer from a thumb drive with ubuntu 10.4 and I have no idea how to uninstall it.

Comment: boot into safe mode and remove the driver there: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-vista

Comment: I've done all that and my computer is working fine again.  The original problem of the DWM not working with a rotated second display is still prevalent.

Comment: do you get a message that DWM.exe has stopped working or what do you mean with crashing?

Comment: It just quits.  The display flickers and then my display changes to a different theme.  There was an error message a few days ago, but I tried it just now and no error message, although the thing still crashed.

Comment: download this .reg file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h81n7hfbc47pw6i/WER_DWM.reg import it and upload the zipped dmp file from C:\localdumps

Comment: Okay... I downloaded the file, against Chrome's wishes, but how do I run it and more importantly, what does it do?  (BTW, thanks so much for trying to help, I really appreciate it)

Comment: simply double click it or run regedit.exe and select under "File"->"Import" the .reg file.